# Not Acceptable! An appropriate representation of the requested resource could not be found on this server

Tags: wordpress

Hola tengo un error desde hace una semana para ingresar al administrador de wordpress, estoy trabajando remotamente y al parecer este error ha saltado desde hace no más de unos dias ya que si he trabajado desde antes desde aquí. El problema esa que aparece esto

> An appropriate representation of the requested resource could not be found on this server. This error was generated by Mod_Security.

Ya he intentado de todo, desativando plugins y temas. Estoy seguro que el problema solo es de mi pc porque mis jefes inmediatos y el cliente no tienen el mismo problema. Estoy intentado desactivar el mod security  desde cpanel pero **BLUEHOST** no permite esa opcion, incluso desde codigo por HTACCESS, tampoco da resultado. Mi inquietud es que es lo que ha cambiado en mi pc para que ahora salte este error. Espero su ayuda

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Andrés:

Este error suele generarlo el módulo de Mod_Security en apache.

Algunos proveedores de hostings tienen este módulo como una capa de seguridad adicional y no permiten desactivarlo desde el panel. Lo normal es contactar al equipo de soporte de tu proveedor de hosting y comentarles este problema para que te ayuden a solucionarlo ya que para ello pagas el servicio.

Sería recomendable que añadieras más información, como lo que te aparece en los logs de errores de apache que normalmente el cliente suele tener acceso. De esta forma, podrías revisar si contienes entradas como la siguiente (suele ser lo normal en estos casos):

```
ModSecurity: Access denied with code 406 (phase 2). Match of “beginsWith
 http://%{SERVER_NAME}/” against “MATCHED_VAR” required. [file 
“/etc/httpd/modsecurity.d/10_asl_rules.conf”] [line “1974”] [id “340595”]
 [rev “16”] [msg “Remote File Injection attempt in ARGS”] [severity “WARNING”]
```

Donde tienes un id, en este caso 340595. Normalmente, suele funcionar añadiéndolo al .htacess de la siguiente forma:

```
<IfModule mod_security.c>
  SecRuleRemoveById 340595
</IfModule>
```

Con esto, por así decirlo, permites esta regla en el servicio.

Esto no es recomendable, dependiendo del tipo de regla te puede ayudar a prevenir actividades maliciosas sobre tu servicio web. Al igual que hay ciertas reglas que no pueden ser permitidas de esta forma ya que son de "nivel mayor de riesgo" y tendría que ser revisada por el proveedor de hosting ya que podría afectar más cosas.

Podrías echarle un ojo a la siguiente URL que parece que le ha sucedido lo mismo con el mismo proveedor de hosting: https://expressionengine.com/forums/topic/252252/problem-with-bluehost-and-mod_security

Como comenté, podrías contactar con el soporte técnico ya que para eso pagas el servicio.

Comment: Gracias Adrian por responder, en realidad nose que informacion más podria brindar para solucionar esto...

En que parte del CPANEL puedo encontrar el LOG de errores, entiendo que hay uno en las directivas PUBLIC HTML / ERROR LOG pero al parecer ahi no aparece el ID para desbloquearlo.

Comment: Hola, Andrés. Es un ejemplo de lo que podría estar sucediendo. De tu proveedor, la verdad, no conozco mucho, aunque muchos tengan cosas en común porque al fin y al cabo son proveedores de servicios de hosting, cada uno tendrá su sistema adaptado a su manera. El único proveedor en el que he estado es Dinahosting y ellos nos dejan en una carpeta de nuestro hosting los logs tanto de acceso como de errores de apache. Ten en cuenta que lo del id es una posibilidad, no digo que pueda ser exactamente eso. Si consigues estos logs de errores de apache y nos puedes proporcionar más información genial.